# How to get the previous value of a row in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

My SSRS report has two groups (Account, Month). Account is Parent and Month is child group. Now I want to show the ending balance of each Month as the Beginning balance of next month. A sample report is given bellow. Red font indicates the SUM of each group. Remember that i am trying to get the result by using SSRS Previous() function, but can't get the expected result.

```
Previous(Sum(Fields!NetAmt.Value),"Month")
```

Month => Month group name.

Can any one help me?

Thanks in advance.

Rashed

Sample SQL Data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Balances](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Account] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Month] [date] NULL,
    [BegBalance] [float] NULL,
    [Debit] [float] NULL,
    [Credit] [float] NULL,
    [EndBalance] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Balances] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Balances] ON
INSERT [dbo].[Balances] ([id], [Account], [Month], [BegBalance], [Debit], [Credit], [EndBalance]) VALUES (1, N'Cash', CAST(0xDB3A0B00 AS Date), 0, 100, 50, 50)
INSERT [dbo].[Balances] ([id], [Account], [Month], [BegBalance], [Debit], [Credit], [EndBalance]) VALUES (2, N'Cash', CAST(0xDB3A0B00 AS Date), 0, 200, 50, 150)
INSERT [dbo].[Balances] ([id], [Account], [Month], [BegBalance], [Debit], [Credit], [EndBalance]) VALUES (3, N'Cash', CAST(0xFA3A0B00 AS Date), 0, 200, 50, 150)
INSERT [dbo].[Balances] ([id], [Account], [Month], [BegBalance], [Debit], [Credit], [EndBalance]) VALUES (4, N'Cash', CAST(0xFA3A0B00 AS Date), 0, 200, 100, 100)
INSERT [dbo].[Balances] ([id], [Account], [Month], [BegBalance], [Debit], [Credit], [EndBalance]) VALUES (5, N'Mr.  Axxx', CAST(0xDB3A0B00 AS Date), 0, 200, 100, 100)
INSERT [dbo].[Balances] ([id], [Account], [Month], [BegBalance], [Debit], [Credit], [EndBalance]) VALUES (6, N'Mr.  Axxx', CAST(0xDB3A0B00 AS Date), 0, 100, 50, 50)
INSERT [dbo].[Balances] ([id], [Account], [Month], [BegBalance], [Debit], [Credit], [EndBalance]) VALUES (7, N'Mr.  Axxx', CAST(0xFA3A0B00 AS Date), 0, 100, 50, 50)
INSERT [dbo].[Balances] ([id], [Account], [Month], [BegBalance], [Debit], [Credit], [EndBalance]) VALUES (8, N'Mr.  Axxx', CAST(0xFA3A0B00 AS Date), 0, 100, 20, 80)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Balances] OFF
```

After Using Previous() function
[image]

Comment: Could you add some sample data? I think it can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LOOKUPSET` function and custom code to get the previous `End Balance` total.

Go to `Report` menu / `Report properties...` in the `Code` tab paste this VB function.

```
Public Function GetBegBal(values As Object) As String
    Dim total As Double = 0
    For Each value As Double In values
                      total = total + value
        Next
    Return total
End Function
```

In the `Beg Balance` use this expression:

```
=Code.GetBegBal(
LOOKUPSET(
Fields!Account.Value & "-" & MONTH(Fields!Month.Value)-1,
Fields!Account.Value & "-" & MONTH(Fields!Month.Value),
Fields!EndBalance.Value,
"DataSetName")
)
```

Replace `DataSetName` by the actual name of yours, then preview your report, it should look like this:

[image]

Note I am using `MONTHNAME` function in the Months column so it returns the name of the month based on the regional and language settings in my machine (Spanish).

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle it in your dataset's SQL query, Try using `LAG()`:

```
SELECT mt.*, beg.begbal FROM [dbo].[Balances] mt
JOIN
(
SELECT [Account]
      ,[Month]
      ,SUM([EndBalance]) EndBal
      ,LAG (SUM([EndBalance]), 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY [Account] ORDER BY [Month] ASC) begbal
  FROM [dbo].[Balances]
  GROUP BY [Account]
      ,[Month]
) beg
ON mt.Month = beg.Month
AND mt.Account = beg.Account
```

**Update:** without using LAG(), try the below code.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT [Account]
      ,[Month]
      ,SUM([EndBalance]) EndBal
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Account] ORDER BY [Month] ASC) RowVal
  FROM [dbo].[Balances]
  GROUP BY [Account]
      ,[Month]
)

SELECT mt.*, ISNULL(t2.EndBal, 0) as begbal FROM CTE t1
LEFT JOIN CTE t2
ON t1.Account = t2.Account AND t1.RowVal = t2.RowVal + 1
JOIN [dbo].[Balances] mt
ON t1.Month = mt.Month AND t1.Account = mt.Account
```

Also, below is the SSRS expression code you are looking for:

```
=IIF
(
(RunningValue(Fields!Month.Value, CountDistinct, "Account")) = 1,
0,
Previous(SUM(Fields!EndBalance.Value),"MonthGrp")
)
```

Comment: LAG() is not supported by SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: Updated the answer with SSRS Expression. Also T-SQL replacement using ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: Thanks for your SSRS expression code. I was actually looking for this. It is perfectly working for me.