# SSRS 2008-r2 - How to use the value from previous column total as start value in following column in a matrix

Tags: t-sql, matrix, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using SSRS 2008-r2.
I have a few matrix's in my report, each has its own dataset.  I need to be able to use the total value from the previous column as the starting value of the next column and that starting value would then be used in the calculation to find the total in that column. Example picture below:

[image: Example of result requirements]

In the Ending Position Cell the expression would be (Starting Position+NewMembers-Cancelled/Resignedmembers-Lapsed) to give the value. The picture example shows the Ending position as 439 which then needs to be used as the starting position for the following month.
My Matrix set up is:

[image: Matrix in report]

The closest question I have found is here but I have not been able to get it to work:
[how-to-get-the-previous-value-of-a-row-in-ssrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39895063/how-to-get-the-previous-value-of-a-row-in-ssrs)
I had a read up on using the lookupset function mentioned in the question but I do not have fields in my datasets for the starting and ending positions.
Is there a way to do this in the matrix? or do I need a separate totals dataset that I use to pull the values into this matrix.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the more simple and straightforward solution is to calculate and include those values as fields in your dataset.

PS It looks like you already have a start and end field in your dataset (BegBal, EndBal)?

Comment: thank you but just to clarify the BegBal and EndBal shown in the dataset popped in automatically when I was trying to test using the report code from the linked StackOverflow post.  They are not actually in my dataset.  I will try to code in the EndBal into my query